# inline form parts using CSS (inline attribute)?

Tags: css, forms, input, inline

I want to create a simple form. The final design should be the one above, but with a responsive positioning.

So I tried to use the inline attribute of css:

```
<!--Name...-->
<div style="display: inline;">
<label for="vorname_patient">Vorname: </label> <br> <input type="text" name="vorname_patient" id="vorname_patient" required="" size="20" autofocus=""> <br>
<label for="nachname_patient">Nachname: </label> <br> <input type="text" name="nachname_patient" id="nachname_patient" required="" size="20">
</div>
<!--Anrede...-->
<div style="display: inline;">
<label for=anrede_patient">Anrede: </label> <br> <input type="text" name="anrede_patient" id="anrede_patient" size="20">
</div>
```

If i run that i will not get any inlineme parts anywhere.

i want to get this (without a table):

https://jsfiddle.net/kcd1qr1r/

What did I do wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements must flow within their nearest block parent. So, because you changed the div containers to be inline, your label and input elements are just flowing within the body (nearest block parent). Use `inline-block` instead or, due to possible margin issues with that approach, you may want to try flexboxes.

Comment: very nice! thats what i was searching for